# Failed assertion: line 4774 pos 14: '_dependents.isEmpty': is not true

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter and I am working on a chat app, and whenever i choose an user i should be able to talk to him in a private way, that's what I am doing, whenever i click someone I try to move to this Chat Screen, and then I am getting this error (see title).

But when I'm pressing the back button and try again it works and shows the chat like it should, this is really confusing me, and if someone have an idea where it comes from, it would be awesome.

Here's my chat.dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:social/responsive/size_config.dart';

var _firestore = Firestore.instance;
FirebaseUser loggedInUser;
String groupChatId;

class Chat extends StatelessWidget {

  static const String id = 'chat_screen';
  final String peerEmail;

  Chat({Key key, @required this.peerEmail}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            'CHAT',
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: ChatScreen(peerEmail: peerEmail));
  }
}

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String peerEmail;

  ChatScreen({this.peerEmail});

  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState(peerEmail: peerEmail);
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final messageTextController = TextEditingController();
  String peerEmail;
  String messageText;

  _ChatScreenState({this.peerEmail});

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
    String email = loggedInUser.email;
    getGroupId(email);
  }

  void getGroupId(String email) {
    if (peerEmail.hashCode <= email.hashCode) {
      setState(() {
        groupChatId = '$peerEmail-$email';
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        groupChatId = '$email-$peerEmail';
      });
    }
  }

  void getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      final user = await _auth.currentUser();
      if (user != null) {
        loggedInUser = user;
        setState(() {});
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        MessageStream(),
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red,borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  controller: messageTextController,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    //Do something with the user input.
                    messageText = value;
                  },

                ),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  //Implement send functionality.
                  messageTextController.clear();
                  print(messageText);
                  print(loggedInUser.email);
                  _firestore.collection('messages')
                      .document(groupChatId)
                      .collection(groupChatId).add({
                    'content': messageText,
                    'emailFrom': loggedInUser.email,
                    'emailTo': peerEmail,
                  });
                },
                child: Text(
                  'Send',

                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )));
  }
}

class MessageStream extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _firestore
          .collection('messages')
          .document(groupChatId)
          .collection(groupChatId)
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.black),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          final messages = snapshot.data.documents;
          List<MessageDisplay> messageList = [];
          for (var msg in messages) {
            final message = msg.data['content'];
            final emailTo = msg.data['emailTo'];
            final emailFrom = msg.data['emailFrom'];
            final messageDisplay = MessageDisplay(
              message: message,
              emailFrom: emailFrom,
              emailTo: emailTo,
            );
            messageList.add(messageDisplay);
          }
          return Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 20.0),
              children: messageList != null ? messageList:CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          );
        } //
      },
    );
  }
}

class MessageDisplay extends StatelessWidget {
  MessageDisplay({this.message, this.emailFrom, this.emailTo});

  final String message;
  final String emailFrom;
  final String emailTo;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(SizeConfig.safeBlockVertical * 3),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          message != null
              ? Text(
                  message,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: SizeConfig.safeBlockVertical * 15,
                    color: Colors.black54,
                  ),
                )
              : CircularProgressIndicator(),
          emailFrom != null
              ? Text(
                  emailFrom,
                )
              : CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause for this type of error is the new screen you are navigating to is trying to access information from the previous screen which it has no access to or has not inherited and therefore doesn't have the correct build context when trying to build causing this error.

Comment: it always more helpful to add some command and codes in your answer.